# Report Builder - Do stored procedures for hidden items still run?

Tags: stored-procedures, charts, reportbuilder

I have to build a dashboard using Report Builder and I have some charts and graphs that have an expression that will hide the charts if a flag is set to `false`.

My question is, when the flag is set to `false` does my stored procedure still run in the background (even though the chart will not be seen when the report is rendered)? Also if the stored procedures are running in the background, is there a way to make them not run?